# Bootstrap "close" Class: Button Sometimes Pushed out of Alert by Text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm wondering if there are any edits I can make on top of bootstrap's css to resolve the following behaviour where my `close` class button sometimes gets pushed out of its alert by the text within.

Most of the time, it appears fine like so:

[image: Button in alert]

But at certain screen widths, just before the text in the alert wraps, the close button no longer has enough room at the end of the alert. In this image, I reduced the screen width by a few pixels compared to the previous image:

[image: Button outside alert]

Here is my code snippet (edited to replace ASP.NET controls and code render blocks):

```
<div class="mt-0 mb-3 alert alert-primary">
    <span class="text-here">foo</span>
    <a class="close">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant HTML / CSS to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi, yes, I'd forgotten about it and posted the question too early. Already on it, one minute please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I'd simply removed one class too many while removing client-side dismiss functionality in favour of an ASP.NET click event postback.

The class in question, **`alert-dismissible`**, which is supposed to go alongside the `alert` class when a close button is present. It adds a larger amount of padding to the right side of the alert div, such that the floating close button/anchor always has enough room to sit at the top right. It also gives the close button some styling, including padding, such that it is nicely centered in that vertical space.

That also explains why my close button was at the bottom right instead. A comment on the main question that got deleted by its OP did point out that the close button looked like it was in a weird position.

Here is my new working code, without any additional custom classes needed:

```
<div class="mt-0 mb-3 alert alert-dismissable alert-primary">
    <span class="text-here">foo</span>
    <a class="close">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Good observation

The green div with `display:inline-block`; & `width` to `100%` should resolve this...

**working snippet** below:

```css
.fixedAlert {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="mt-0 mb-3 alert alert-success fixedAlert">
    <span class="text-here"> FIXED ALERT... I'm wondering if there are any edits I can make on top of bootstrap's css to resolve the following behaviour where my close class button sometimes gets pushed out of its alert by the text within</span>
    <button type="button" class="close">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="mt-0 mb-3 alert alert-primary ">
    <span class="text-here"> ORIGINAL ALERT... I'm wondering if there are any edits I can make on top of bootstrap's css to resolve the following behaviour where my close class button sometimes gets pushed out of its alert by the text within</span>
    <button type="button" class="close">
        <span>&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated**: in light of questioner's comment below

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid that setting its width to 100 of the viewwidth causes the alert to overflow to the right of the page. My alert is currently inside a bootstrap container.

Comment: Thank you for the response yet again. I tried your updated solution. Adding `w-100` doesn't appear to do anything. As for adding `d-inline-block`, that did cause the `alert` div to start taking the floating inline anchor into account alongside the inline span, but in the end, I inspected bootstrap's alert examples carefully and realised that I'd simply removed one class too many while removing client-side dismiss functionality. I'll answer my own question.